# Adding elements from the list to a dictionary as key-value pairs in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to Python and I'm currently working by solving questions to improve my coding skills. I have two `Lists` with equal sizes and I want to add those values from the lists into a `dictionary` as key-value pairs. How can I do that? From my research, I found that I could use the `dict` to add the elements from the list to a dictionary as only keys or values.

Example:

```
List_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
List_2 = [11, 12, 13, 14]
```

My dictionary should contain:

```
<'1':'11', '2':'12', '3':'13', '4':'14'>
```

My code: `d = dict.fromkeys(List_1, 0)` - but this only adds the elements in `List_1` as keys and 0's as values. But if i replace the 0 with `List_2`, the output is quite weird and not as expected.

Please help me in understanding this. Thanks in advance. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for my poor search, thanks for pointing the approach for this.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't `dict(zip(List_1, List_2))` work?  In this case, you'll get a dictionary of `int` rather than a dictionary of strings. . .

Comment: yes it did work. Thank you.